# How to use XNA in WPF?

Tags: xna, c#, wpf

How can I render some graphics using XNA to a widget/control in a WPF app? Specifically, I don't need any WPF controls inside the XNA graphics window, I just want to put some controls around it for a level editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nick Gravelyn explains how to do it on his blog.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/nicgrave/rendering-with-xna-framework-4-0-inside-of-a-wpf-application)

Although, if it's just for an editor, you may find using [WinForms](https://web.archive.org/web/20150116165519/http://create.msdn.com:80/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1) is easier and better supported.

Comment: Really? I only made the switch because WPF is all the rage. I don't mind WinForms at all actually...never really cared for XAML. Binding is pretty cool though....gotta figure out the equivalent of binding in WinForms...

Comment: I don't have a good site suggestion so I'll just provide this google search:
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=DataBinding+WinForms&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g6

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to snag the Direct3D render target handle and hook it up with D3DImage.  I've done this successfully with WPF and XNA 3.1, but I had some issues with XNA 4.0 because they changed the surface format mappings.  But supposedly other people have gotten it working with XNA 4.0.